# Sorting JSON Data by date

Tags: objective-c, json, sorting, date

Hi I'm getting data online from a JSON file and I'm trying to sort it by date in descending order, I've done it before using an XML parser using an RSS feed and tried to use the same concept but can't seem to get it and it crashes every time.

```
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
   NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

   NSDictionary *dataDict = [dict objectForKey:@"data"];
   NSArray *array = [dataDict objectForKey:@"items"];

   for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {


    SongInfo *song = [[SongInfo alloc]init];
    NSMutableDictionary *entry = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    song.uploaded = [entry objectForKey:@"uploaded"];
    song.uploader = [entry objectForKey:@"uploader"];


    NSComparator comparator = ^(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) {
        return [a[@"uploaded"] compare:b[@"uploaded"]];
    };
    NSUInteger index = [songsArray indexOfObject:entry
                              inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, [songsArray count])
                                    options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex
                            usingComparator:comparator];

    [songsArray insertObject:song atIndex:index];
```

EDIT: Managed to fix it by using the NSSortDescriptor and putting it into an array and then back into the same array, not sure if there is a better way to do this but this is how I did it...

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"uploaded"
                                                 ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [songsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    songsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];
   // [songsArray addObject:[song copy] atIndex:index];

   [songsArray addObject:song];
```

Comment: It crashes? With what error? Which line?

Comment: Sorry should have said
[SongInfo objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x974e070

Comment: Assuming that the second line works as expected, JSON really doesn't factor into this question at all.

Comment: JSON represented in a collection classes not a data model. Create a data model organized by the apps needs and populate that model from the JSON. Then create methods in the model to provide the results you need.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing objects inserted in the songsArray with a comparator that takes in two dictionaries. It seems like the comparator should compare SongInfo objects rather than NSDictionaries.

Comment: Makes sense, but I get an error saying "incompatible block pointer types initializing '__strong NSComp..."

Answer (score 1):

We can't see what songsArray is. Creating a sorted array manually like you do is really inefficient. Call the NSArray method sortedArrayUsingComparator instead, and there is no need to create SongInfo objects.

On the other hand, if an array of SongInfo* is what you want, create that array first as an NSMutableArray with all the SongInfo's from the JSON data, then sort that array by calling sortUsingComparator.

Note that in the comparator block you can actually use the type of the object: So in the first case NSDictionary* instead of id, in the second case SongInfo* instead of id.